# Is there a way to install gmsh 3.0.4 in Anaconda?

Tags: pip, conda, mesh, gmsh

I want to use gmsh API to create meshes. I had already installed gmsh 4.11.1 but it has some problems so I want to use an older version.

I tried to install gmsh 3.0.4 using `pip install gmsh==3.0.4` but I get this error:

> 'ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gmsh==3.0.6 (from versions: 4.9.0, 4.9.0.post1, 4.9.1, 4.9.2, 4.9.3, 4.9.4, 4.9.5, 4.10.0, 4.10.1, 4.10.2, 4.10.3, 4.10.4, 4.10.5, 4.11.0, 4.11.1)'

I don't want to use any of the above listed versions. I want to use any version below 4.0.

I am using windows 11 and the latest version of anaconda.

Comment: While `conda-forge` channel does provide `gmsh=3.0.6` (the binary), the Python API (`python-gmsh`) was never built for that. There is [a request for such a build](https://github.com/conda-forge/gmsh-feedstock/issues/57), so please add your voice there to communicate demand to the feedstock maintainers.